# Java-SCJP question

Tags: java

Consider:

```
class Building {
    Building() {
        System.out.print("b ");
    }
    Building(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.print("bn "+name);
    }
}
public class House extends Building {
    House() {
        System.out.print("h ");
    }
    House(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.print("hn "+name);
    }
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        new House("x ");
    }
}
```

For the above program, I thought the output must be h hn x. But the output comes  as b h hn x.

Why?

Later

```
public class TestDays {

    public enum Days {
        MON,TUE,WED
    };
    public static void main(String []args) {

        for(Days d : Days.values())
        ;
        Days [] d2=Days.values();
        System.out.println(d2[2]);

    }

}
```

I can't understand the above program. Please help me.

```
class Mammal {

    String name="furry";
    String makeNoise() {
        return "generic noise";
    }

}

class Zebra extends Mammal {

    String name="stripes";
    String makeNoise() {
        return "bray";
    }

}
public class ZooKeeper {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ZooKeeper().go();
    }
    void go() {

        Mammal m=new Zebra();
        System.out.println(m.name+m.makeNoise());

    }

}
```

In the above program, makeNoise() is overridden. And so output must be stripes bray. But the output is furry bray.

Comment: You asked three unconnected questions in one go.  This makes answering them messy.  In future, ask each question as a separate SO Question.

Answer (score 3):

Problem 1:

> I thought the output must be h hn x. But the output comes as b h hn x.

You are missing the fact that the `House()` constructor **implicitly** invokes the no-args constructor of `Building`.

Problem 2:

> I cant understand the above program. Please help me.

It is printing the 3rd value of the enumeration.  The empty for-loop looks a bit strange, but I suspect that's just a typing error.  If there is something else you don't understand, you'll have to say what it is.  (I left my mind-reading helmet at home ... and Jon Skeet is asleep.)

Problem 3:

> In the above program, makeNoise() is overridden. And so output must be stripes bray. But the output is furry bray.

The reason you are seeing "furry" instead of "stripes" is that *attributes* of a class are **NOT** overridden.  A Zebra instance actually has two fields called `name`, and your code binds to one or the other depending on the declared type of the reference variable.  In this case, the declared type of `m` is `Mammal` so you are getting the mammal version of the name.

Answer (score 2):

1.- b appears first because this code:

```
House() {
    System.out.print("h ");
}
```

First call the super class no args constructor ( that's done by the compiler ) so you should think about it as:

```
House() {
    super();
    System.out.print("h ");
}
```

2- Your're declaring a [Java enum](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+enum)

The for loop iterates all the possible values ( MON, TUE, WED )

```
    for(Days d : Days.values())
    ;
```

But, it doesn't do anything  ( see the ; that means "nothing" )

And then, creates an array with those values

```
    Days [] d2=Days.values();
```

To finally print the 3rd position ( arrays in Java are zero based, so 0-1-2 is the 3rd position )

```
    System.out.println(d2[2]);
```

Which prints WED

3.- See [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243068/java-scjp-question/3243112#3243112) answer.  You're getting the super class attribute.